# Test case fails in IntelliJ but succeed in terminal

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Java unit test case that runs successfully in terminal using `gradle test` but fails in IntelliJ whether I ran just a single test case or the whole test class.

The actual failure is for some reason, a constructor of an object is not called (I debugged using break point, and did not catch it) hence a parameter was not set correctly.

How come IntelliJ does not execute the constructor as is? Any ideas or tips?

Comment: It is hard to debug invisible code

Comment: IntelliJ has its own test runner - the question is what is the gradle script doing that IntelliJ is not. The absence of any sort of code would sort of preclude any intelligent answer to this.

Comment: Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also delegate run actions to Gradle: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html .

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry I don't have the liberty to share the code as is. And it is meaningless to share changed code. 

Thanks for the link to Gradle delegate, it is irony that I have already enabled that option and it is not working. Now I just disabled that option and now it is working! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else happens to hit similar issues, this was because I enabled "Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle", thanks for @CrazyCoder sharing the link and inspiring me.

After I disable that option, the test worked and passed as normal. Thanks again to @CrazyCoder!